# Make layer stacking in ENVI for Landsat 8

Tags: layers, vector, envi

I downloaded Landsat image 8 and I made layer stacking for RGB layers in ENVI (Bands 4,3,2) to classify the land cover types. But the problem appeared when I conducted supervised classification.

I attached three figures;

- A: Layer stacking RGB,
- B: ROI,
- C: Supervised Classification

Why the supervised classified image appears like C?

[image] 
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what are the steps you followed to do supervised classification, but long time ago I used to follow the instructions of the [ENVI Classification Tutorial](https://www.harrisgeospatial.com/docs/ClassificationTutorial.html) and it worked very well. I do not have ENVI anymore, but it seems you did not select the Landsat image as an input to apply the classification on, so this might be the issue.

Also there are many Youtube videos showing how to perform supervised classification such as:

- [Supervised classification example using ENVI 5.1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ImC-e62UQZM)
- [Supervised Landsat Image Classification using ENVI 5.3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lYo6E1CpLmY)

Try to follow the above tutorials and it may help understand how to do supervised classification properly.